# How is UV light generated in equipment?

Tags: visible-light, laser

I have been wanting to build a spectrophotometer, or a device that emits light in the UV range for measuring properties of proteins in my graduate lab.

I am thus looking to find a way to generate UV light, and have looked online at the options. There are 'broadband' UV lamps and LED's available at fixed wavelengths but this seems pretty restrictive. On top of that, it seems pretty hard to buy these things. Anything below 350nm becomes super expensive, and the ordering process becomes a little more 'beaurocratic' than an online cart.

If you can simply run current through a tungsten filament to make broadband visible light, is there a similar process for UV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be very careful with generating UV. UV will generate ozone from oxygen in the air and if you are creating enough of it (eg for broadband spectoscopy) then it will be essential that it is well enclosed and ventilated.

For UV, specialised coatings for the optics are needed. These need careful cleaning; ensuring there is no water contamination.

For blackbody radiation, ridiculous temperatures are needed to push the peak into the UV; well beyond what even tungsten can handle. Atomic transitions exist in the UV but require fluorescence or other effects to make them anything but narrowband sources, which would be no good for spectroscopy. UV supercontinuum generation is also a possibility.

There are good practical reasons why such equipment is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The output of a tungsten filament bulb has little UV content. To make lots of UV the  process is to use what is called a UV/mercury vapor bulb. This differs from a "conventional" mercury vapor bulb in that it is missing the outer glass envelope which blocks the UV from leaving the inner vapor capsule when the bulb is operating, and thus prevents people working under the bulb from getting badly sunburned. These are commercially available and are sold to cure adhesives and inks that are UV-curable. Search for "UV curing bulb".